# Transform HBase Scan to RowFilter

Tags: scala, google-cloud-bigtable, spotify-scio

I'm using [scio](https://github.com/spotify/scio) from spotify for my Dataflow jobs.
In last scio version, new bigtable java api is used (com.google.bigtable.v2)

Now [scio bigtable entry point](https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/874407a16e8801b44c3c295f64891f89e0c43e45/scio-bigtable/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/bigtable/package.scala#L107) required "RowFilter" to filter instead of Hbase "Scan". Is there a simple way to transform "Scan" to "RowFilter" ? I looked for [adapters](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/master/bigtable-hbase-parent/bigtable-hbase/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/adapters/filters/PrefixFilterAdapter.java) in source code but I'm not sure how to use it.
I don't find documentation to easy migrate from hbase api to "new" api.

A simple scan I used in my code that I need to transform:

```
val scan = new Scan()
scan.setRowPrefixFilter("helloworld".getBytes)
scan.addColumn("family".getBytes, "qualifier".getBytes)
scan.setMaxVersions()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you can add the [bigtable-hbase dependency](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22bigtable-hbase%22) to the project and call `com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.Adapters.SCAN_ADAPTER.adapt(scan)` to convert the `Scan` to a `RowFilter`, or more specifically a `[ReadRowsRequest][3]` which contains a `[RowFilter][4]`.  (The links are to the protobuf definition of those objects which contain the variables and extensive comments).

That said, the bigtable-hbase dependency adds quite a few transitive dependencies.  I would use the bigtable-hbase SCAN_ADAPTER in a standalone project, and then print the RowFilter to see how it's constructed.

In the specific case that you mention, the `RowFilter` is quite simple, but there may be additional complications.  You have three parts to your scan, so I'll give a breakdown of how to achieve them:

1. `scan.setRowPrefixFilter("helloworld".getBytes)`.  This translates to a start key and end key on `BigtableIO`.  "helloworld" is the start key, and you can calculate the end key with [`RowKeyUtil. calculateTheClosestNextRowKeyForPrefix`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/bigtable-client-0.9.7.1/bigtable-client-core-parent/bigtable-client-core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/util/RowKeyUtil.java#L39).  The default `BigtableIO` does not expose set start key and set end key, so the scio version will have to change to make those setters public.
2. `scan.addColumn("family".getBytes, "qualifier".getBytes)` translates to two `RowFilter`s added to a `RowFilter` with a `Chain` (mostly analogous to an AND).  The first `RowFilter` will have familyNameRegexFilter set, and the second `RowFilter` will have columnNameRegexFilter
3. `scan.setMaxVersions()` converts to a `RowFilter` with `cellsPerColumnLimitFilter` set.  It would need to be added to a the chain from #2.  Warning: If you use a `timestampRangeFilter` or value filter of a `RowFilter` to limit the range of the columns, make sure to put the `cellsPerColumnLimitFilter` at the end of the chain.

Comment: Thanks for help ! "adapt" method from "SCAN_ADAPATER" has a second required parameter called "readHooks", do you have any explications how to use it ? I tried innocently with null but it doesn't work. Scio exposes "keyRange" https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/master/scio-bigtable/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/bigtable/package.scala#L118, do you think it can be used for RangeFilter ? Scio seems to patch existing BigtableIO with "PatchedBigtableIO.java". For setMaxVersions I'm a bit surprised, I used it in some jobs and It seemed to work.

Comment: The scan adapter should take a new DefaultReadHooks() as the second parameter.  I was wrong about the setMaxVersions().  I was thinking about PageFilter.  I'm going to edit my comment.